# Setting Spinner background to null programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-spinner

I'm trying to set the background of a Spinner to null programmatically as would the following XML code:

```
<Spinner
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/spinner1"
   android:background="@null"
/>
```

I tried either of:

```
spinner1.setBackground(null);

spinner1.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

spinner1.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

But none of these three give the same output as the xml. Via xml, the whole arrow region disappears, including padding, whereas via code, only the arrow sign disappears but the full length of the arrow region remains.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Just set it to Transparent instead. Make a style for the spinner, or simply set it's background="#00000000"

or if you want to do it in code you could use a style swap or simply declare a drawable.

```
Drawable transparentDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mySpinner.setBackground(transparentDrawable);
```

Note* make sure you use the correct setBackground for the correct OS as it deprecated and moved from setBackgroundDrawable after lollipop I believe it was.

Comment: I need to do it programmatically. I believe that styles and background="#..." only work from XML.

Comment: updated to make drawable in code if that is your preference

Comment: Not working either. There is still some space at right of the drop-down. The xml solution totally removes that blank.

Comment: ok well if XML solution works, then just make a style for the spinner and apply it